# generate 2 different random numbers from an Array?

Tags: javascript

my only issue so far is when the ships have the same value, I get an error message if I'm using VSC.
TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
I was trying to get to different values by using the condition but I think it doesn't work.

```js
let grid = [[]];
const letters = "abc".toUpperCase();

// create the Grid


const createGrid = (size) => {
  let row;
  let col = 0;
  for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    grid[row] = [];
    for (col = 0; col < size; col++) {
    grid[row][col] = `${letters[row]}${col + 1}`;
    }
  }

};

createGrid(letters.length);
console.table(grid);

// Start the game


//create ships



const flatArray = grid.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return [...acc, ...curr];
}, []);

function getRandomNumber(len) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
}


const randomNumber1 = getRandomNumber(flatArray.length);
const randomNumber2 = getRandomNumber(flatArray.length);

while(randomNumber1 == randomNumber2) {
  getRandomNumber();
}

var shipOne = flatArray[randomNumber1];
var shipTwo = flatArray[randomNumber2];



console.log(shipOne);
console.log(shipTwo);
```

Comment: Assignment to constant variable error is related to declare variable with `const` and later reassigning a value to that variable. I don't see any of this happening here, so I think it maybe somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, try to summarize your problem and what you tried instead of posting a lot of unrelated code and having us guess what you need. Sometimes, isolating your issue into a self-contained example will help you find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other approach you could try is to create a function `pickRandomEntries()` that will pick N random entries from an array, without ever picking the same ones.

To do this, we shuffle a copy of your `flatArray()`, then pick the first two items.

This way we never have to check for the ships having the same value:

```js
let grid = [[]];
const letters = "abc".toUpperCase();

const createGrid = (size) => {
  let row;
  let col = 0;
  for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    grid[row] = [];
    for (col = 0; col < size; col++) {
    grid[row][col] = `${letters[row]}${col + 1}`;
    }
  }
};

createGrid(letters.length);

const flatArray = grid.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return [...acc, ...curr];
}, []);

// Shuffle an array into a random order (using Fisher-Yates)
function shuffle(arr) {
    for(let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [arr[index], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[index]];
    }
    return arr;
}

// Pick count random items from the array
function pickRandomEntries(arr, count) {
    let shuffled = shuffle([...arr]);
    return shuffled.slice(0, count);
}

let [shipOne, shipTwo] = pickRandomEntries(flatArray, 2);
console.log( { shipOne, shipTwo });
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Fix an infinite loop

I created a snippet from your example code and it runs forever in the error case you are describing.

A problem is that you have a while loop that will run forever:

```js
while(randomNumber1 == randomNumber2) {
  getRandomNumber();
}
```

You run this code as long as `randomNumber1` and `randomNumber2` are the same but you update neither of them in the loop so it can never be false.

Try this:

```js
while(randomNumber1 == randomNumber2) {
  randomNumber2 = getRandomNumber(flatArray.length);
}
```

You might also make your code a little smarter and *remove* elements from the `flatArray` array you have already chosen.

Comment: Thanks, I just did what you mentioned and now my code works.

Comment: You're welcome. Also corrected my solution, you write `getRandomNumber(flatArray.length);` of course.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your while loop if the two random numbers were the same you would be stuck inside an infinite loop. Like Peter stated.

To fix this use the code Peter stated but don't forget you still need to pass in the array length into this function. Otherwise you will have an error:

```js
while(randomNumber1 == randomNumber2) {
  randomNumber2 = getRandomNumber(flatArray.length);
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, I did what he said and my code works but I added the flatArray.length. thanks for your help